# How to save high-definition maps with tmap in R?

Tags: r, tmap

usually, to save maps in vector format with tmap I use the following command:

```
tmap_save(maps, filename = "maps.pdf",height = 8.27, width = 11.69)
```

However, the results are unsatisfactory in terms of image quality when I import the pdf file into the document. I would like to know if there is anything else I need to consider in order to do this correctly. Thank you.

Comment: What does the code to generate the map look like? As you say, pdf output is generally in vector format, so the quality of polygons should scale to any size. Is there a raster base layer?

Comment: In what kind of document do you import the saved pdf? If it's e.g. a Latex generated document, then pdf should work, otherwise I would suggest to export as png from tmap.

Comment: @SamR There isn't a raster base layer, the map looks like grid polygons

Comment: @mgrund actually I import the pdf in a word document, do you think this could be the problem?

Comment: Could be, as I mentioned I would prefer png as format when using the figures in a Word document.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to mgrund's answer. Why do you need to save maps in vector format? If you are only pasting the figures in the word document, you can export as png, and use the 'dpi' argument in tm_save() to increase resolution for raster images.

```
tmap_save(maps, filename = "maps.png",height = 8.27, width = 11.69, dpi=600)
```

Comment: Hello xfl1234, thanks for your answer. I was trying to find a good solution for adding maps to my word document that I need to convert into pdf. Vector format as you know preserve the resolution also if you increase the zoom

Comment: You're right, but as afaik Word does not support to display vector graphics as e.g. Latex does. Thus, I would export as png and increase the dpi (e.g. 300 or 600) to get a higher resolution before adding to your Word file.